# Binary for each CFLAGS alternative

Tags: makefile, compiler-flags

I need seven binaries maked from the same set of source codes and headers. All of the codes must be compiled with the same `CFLAGS`. In my problem, there are 7 alternatives for `CFLAGS`:

1. `CFLAGS=-O0`
2. `CFLAGS=-O1`
3. `CFLAGS=-O1 -no-vec`
4. `CFLAGS=-O2`
5. `CFLAGS=-O2 -no-vec`
6. `CFLAGS=-O3`
7. `CFLAGS=-O3 -no-vec`

What is the shortest and most suitable way to compile all source codes using `make`?

Answer (score 2):

### Overriding variable CFLAGS from command line?

I suggest you to use [overriding](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding.html) variable CFLAGS from command line.
For this particular case the set of shell commands looks like:

```
make CFLAGS=-O0;          mv binary binary1; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O1;          mv binary binary2; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O1\ -no-vec; mv binary binary3; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O2;          mv binary binary4; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O2\ -no-vec; mv binary binary5; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O3;          mv binary binary6; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O3\ -no-vec; mv binary binary7; make clean;
```

This will allow you to keep makefile simple as for the case with one `CFLAGS` value.
But there is one problem with this method. For creating seven binaries, each time after calling `make` you should move newly created binary. This can be solved by introducing the 
`TARGET` variable for the name of the particular target.

```
make CFLAGS=-O0           TARGET=binary1; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O1           TARGET=binary2; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O1\ -no-vec  TARGET=binary3; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O2           TARGET=binary4; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O2\ -no-vec  TARGET=binary5; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O3           TARGET=binary6; make clean;
make CFLAGS=-O3\ -no-vec  TARGET=binary7; make clean;
```